# How to classify textual data, and calculate quantity in Python

Tags: python

I am a python beginner. I encountered some problems. Hope you can help, thank you.

I have some data in a file a1.txt with the following format:

```
1234,joe,12.34
2355,polly,35.4
```

in my python file A2.py I have this code:

```
fileObject = open("a1.txt","r") #read date
data = fileOject.read()
if data == None
    print(No Records)#display Record is 0 
else
    print("Data records quantity[{}]") #display records quantity
    print("Id:[{}],name:[{}],number:[{}]") 

file.close()
```

I need to display the data in the following way:

```
Data records quantity[2]
Id:[1234],name:[joe],number:[12,34]
Id:[2355],name:[polly],number:[35.4]
```

if no date in a1.txt then display
Records is [0]

Comment: What exactly is your question about this? Your code has some syntax errors, you should fix them first.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code contains quite a few typos, which should be fixed first (e.g `date = fileOject.read()` fileObject is misspelled).

Here is an example of working solution with comments:

```
# open file for reading and return file descriptor
fileObject = open('a1.txt', 'r')
# read all lines from the file
lines = fileObject.readlines()

print(f'Data records quantity[{len(lines)}]')

# go through each line and parse the contents
# assume that has the form of (integer,string,float)
# and separated by comma (e.g 1234,joe,12.34)
for line in lines:
    # split data line in parts by comma
    parts = line.split(',')
    id = int(parts[0])  # first part is id
    name = parts[1]  # second part is name
    number = float(parts[2])  # third part is number
    print(f'Id:[{id}],name:[{name}],number:[{number}]')

fileObject.close()
```

Moreover, it is a good practice to use `with` for file stuff. Instead of writing

```
fileObject = open('a1.txt', 'r')
...
fileObject.close()
```

you can simply do

```
with open('a1.txt', 'r') as fileObject:
    ...
```

which will ensure that file is closed, thus you would not forget to do it manually. Profit!

Good luck with your coding journey =)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question, You can try this code:

```
fileObject = open("mioFile.txt","r") #read date
data = fileObject.readlines()
if data == None:
    print("No Records")#display Record is 0 
else:
    print("Data records quantity["+str(len(data))+"]") #display records quantity
    for items in data:
        item=items.split(",")
        print("Id:[{"+str(item[0])+"}],name:[{"+str(item[1])+"}],number:[{"+str(item[2])+"}]")         
    #print("Id:[{}],name:[{}],number:[{}]") 
    #print data

fileObject.close()
```

I tested it and works.
I get this output when in the mioFile.txt
I write the rows:

> 1234,joe,12.34 2355,polly,35.4
>
> #output Data records quantity[2]   Id:[1234],name:[joe],number:[12,34]  Id:[2355],name:[polly],number:[35.4]